# D3 linear scale , how to show customised strings as ticks ?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a d3 graph plotted which denotes some data over the last 30 days. So my x axis is a linear scale because I am not using dates(instead using number of days). Now to show the x axis , I use code some thing like

```
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .outerTickSize(15)
          .ticks(4)
```

This gives me four ticks like the following:
[image]

Now my problem is that instead of these ticks(numbers), I want to show tick labels from the following array :

```
var xArray = ['one month ago', '3 weeks ago', '2 weeks ago', '1 week ago', 'today'];
```

Any idea how to do this ? (I guess I cannot use ordinal scale because the graph being plotted uses linear scale, I cant mess with that)

Comment: I think I know what you need, but could you supply a plunker? (plnkr.co)

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin did you have the same suggestion as the answer below ? It does work

Comment: Yeah actually. Good job figuring it out.

Answer (score 4):

This should have occured to me earlier that I could use a different(ordinal) scale just for the axis purpose. Anyway might help someone with a same doubt

```
var xScaleForAxis = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(xArray)
          .rangePoints([0, WIDTH]);
```

Now I can use this scale something like following to get the desired result.

```
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(xScaleForAxis)
          .orient("bottom")
          .innerTickSize(-HEIGHT)
          .ticks(4)
```

This gives me the following desired result.

[image]